# HttpWebRequest timing out, but no packets leaving client

Tags: c#, timeout, httpwebrequest, wireshark

I have a c# application with the following requirements.

1. Periodically(700ms) send data to a cgi using a GET.
2. The server will respond with only the GET string sent as confirmation.
3. Values sent are constantly changing and are not stored, ordered, or retried.
4. Only one connection made to the server at a time.
5. Timer events that find a previous connection still in progress should simply exit quietly and let the next event carry on.

The client machine is Windows Server 2012. The HTTP server is a black box appliance(believed to be running linux). Environment is low-latency production with extremely tight security(network/policies/etc).

The problem:
Periodically, the client will begin throwing exceptions

> "The operation timed out"

and the drip feed stops. Simultaneously, Wireshark shows

> no connections being made from the client to the server.

However, VisualStudio shows that

> every 700ms the client is attempting to connect and is timing out.

When it's not throwing the above exception, it seems to work fine. At no time does the HTTP server appear to be rejecting connections. Sometimes the client will recover, most of the time it will continue to throw exceptions until restarted. AppDomain thread pool is stable. Memory consumption is fine.

To confuse matters, I have identical hardware/software/network without the security in a lab where everything runs flawlessly for days at a time. My code is being fingered as "malfunctory".

I have recently discovered that the `HttpWebRequest.Timeout` property bounds the entire life of the transaction, not just the response wait. I am increasing this and it's currently under test.

Anyone see anything glaring(or otherwise) that would cause this problem in the below code?

```
// timer call back at 700ms interval
void m_postTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Interlocked.Read(ref this.m_isLocked) == 0)
        {
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(this.m_lock, 10))
            {
                 Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.m_isLocked, 1);

                try
                {
                    // value1 & value2 set elsewhere
                    string url = String.Format("http://1.1.1.1/set.cgi?value1={0}&value2={1}", value1, value2);

                    this.m_post = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

                    this.m_post.Timeout = 500;

                    this.m_post.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.user, this.pass);

                    WebResponse response = this.m_post.GetResponse();

                    response.Close();

                    Monitor.Exit(this.m_lock);

                    Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.m_isLocked, 0);
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    // handle web exceptions

                    // if we've locked earlier and hit an exception, 
                    // the unlock has been skipped. unlock
                    if (Interlocked.Read(ref this.m_isLocked) > 0)
                    {
                        Monitor.Exit(this.m_lock);

                        Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.m_isLocked, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // indicate that a pre-existing connection is still in progress
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle generic exception

        // if we've locked earlier and hit an exception, 
        // the unlock has been skipped. unlock
        if (Interlocked.Read(ref this.m_isLocked) > 0)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(this.m_lock);

            Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.m_isLocked, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Try simplifying that code. Just for troubleshooting purposes, get rid of all that locking stuff, and just use the basics. Also, BTW, your `WebResponse` should be in a `using` block. Also, did you intend for this to use the `POST` verb? Unless it's the default (don't think so), you haven't set that. You also haven't set any data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response John. I included your recommendation for a using() statement as well as setting the DefaultConnectionLimit in the ServicePointManager to 20. I haven't been able to get clean runs yet(keeps getting killed).

Comment: Still haven't simplified it. I mean for troubleshooting purposes. You can put the complexity back once you get the simple version to work.